# Heroku: detaching from the build process

Tags: git, heroku

The build process on Heroku is started automatically on a git push, and the client waits for the output of the build.

As per the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#detaching-from-the-build-process), you can detach from the build process by pressing ctrl+c, and the build continues in the background, which is fine.

However, I would like to achive that the git push command doesn't even try to wait for the build result. This could be an automatic detach or simply having Heroku to somehow run the build in the background or anything I can think of.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you hook up the "automatic deploys from Github", you can just push it to Github, and Heroku will see that and begin the deploy on their end.

Comment: You could always run the command in the background on _your_ machine. For example, if you're on bash something like `git push heroku master &`. Does this meet your needs? If so, I can add a proper answer below.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you, this could be a workaround but I am working on a closed source pet project so github is not an option. Using for example bitbucket also doesn't work because of its low build time limit.

Comment: @Chris not really, I look for a way in which I do a push and receive information whether it was successful in the context of source control, but don't have to wait for a build. I don't get why it is forced by Heroku, there should be a way to get around it.

Comment: @balee Github has private repositories. You're saying "there should be a way to get around it", but pushing to Github **is** Heroku's way to get around it.

Comment: @ceejayoz hmmm weird way, if it is by design.